# "Bring out" vs. "come out with"

Tags: word-usage

1. The company had already decided to *bring out* a new version of the car.
2. The company had already decided to *come out with* a new version of the car.

I think these 2 sentences are both correct.

1. Apple are bringing out a new cell phone. (Why does this seem incorrect?)
2. Apple are coming out with a new cell phone.

Comment: What makes you think it sounds incorrect?

Comment: It just doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: "bring out" implies that they are *physically* unveiling the device/car/etc. This is correct, for example, in an event where a person is physically moving the item in question to a location where people can see it. If you are talking about the more abstract sense of "releasing an item to the public," you would use "coming out with."

Comment: Another way to say this is, "releasing a new cell phone." There are *many* ways to state this. BTW, in the USA, "Apple *is*..." In the UK, as you wrote, "Apple are..."

Comment: @Esther I strongly disagree with the distinction you make here. I ,might say, and I have red many uses of "bring out" meaning  to publish or release. "Bring out" is the most usual US form for the release of a new model of automobile, and a common form for the release of a new electronic device. It is common for a new book: "Penguin is bringing out Smith's new novel next month".

Comment: @Esther See the 24 "bringing out" examples in my answer, in none of which is the speaker *physically* bringing out something. See also the Google Ngrams linked in that answer..

Answer (score 1):

In US English one might say either:

> - Apple is bringing out a new cell phone.
> - Apple is coming out with a new cell phone.

I think "bringing out" is rather more common, but both are grammatically valid. Either would be understood by a fluent speaker, and there is no significant difference in meaning.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+bringing+out%2Cis+coming+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) shows "is bringing out" to be **significantly** more common than "is coming out with" for all periods since 1800, and all relevant sets of text. The usual cautions of Google Ngrams apply, some examples may be using these words in a quite different grammatical pattern, and this captures printed books, not speech.

Even so, the difference in reported usage is non-trivial.

In response to a comment by user "randomhead", I did [another Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+brought+out%2Chas+come+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20brought%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20come%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0) for the past tense version. It shows that "has brought out" is significantly moe common in the corpus that Google uses than "has come out with". The related Google books search includes such examples as:

- "The hot weather has brought out all the blossom on the fruit trees" ... . "Will the sunshine bring out the rose?" "Ramesh Publishing House has brought out an immensely valuable and useful book titled 'Word Power'" from *For Complete Master Over Written & Spoken English Phrasal Verbs in Daily Use* By J. K. Arora · 2018 ISBN: 9788183481526 (a ‘Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs) [page 14]
- "However, so far the Institute has brought out 33 publications in the form of bibliographies and checklists. Gujarat University Library brought out the list of books on ( a ) education, ..". from *Social Science Information in India: Efforts Towards  Bibliographical Control*
  By S. D. Vyas · 1992 - Page 149 ISBN 9788170224457.
- "It has brought out in the past a publication, *Doctorates in Social Sciences*" from *Development of Library Services in India: Social Science* S. P. Agrawal, ‎Suren Agrawal · 1989  Page 34
- "Some particles can be shifted to the right of the succeeding noun: ELBS has brought out a new book. ELBS has brought a new book out." from *Adv Communicative Eng* - Page 53 by Krishna Mohan, Meenakshi Raman, ‎Meenakshi Raman · 2010
- "Mr Shukla has brought out three books this year" from *Learners' English Grammar And Composition (On Modern Lines)* by
  N.D.V. Prasada Rao · 2000 [page 148]
- "... who has brought out two novels with a major publisher. " from *Out of Russia: Fictions of a New Translingual Diaspora - [Page 50] by Adrian Wanner · 2011
- "Thermo-Calc has brought out a new HEA thermodynamic database (TCHEA) to assist researchers in the calculations in multicomponent space." from *High-Entropy Alloys* - [Page xiii] by B.S. Murty, ‎Jien-Wei Yeh, ‎S. Ranganathan · 2019
- "As for Ted Hughes , he has brought out a new collection entitled Rain - Charm for the Duchy" from *Outcasts from Eden: Ideas of Landscape in British Poetry* .[Page xv] by Edward Picot · 1997
- "She has brought out numerous books and articles in national and international literary magazines." from *India-Pakistan: Partition Perspectives in Indo-English Novels* by V. Pala Prasada Rao, ‎K. Nirupa Rani, ‎Digumarti Bhaskara Rao · 2004
- "AMD has brought out ATI and developed Puma, a new range of chips for laptops." from *EBOOK: Microeconomics* - [Page 584] by Wyn Morgan, ‎Michael Katz, ‎Harvey Rosen · 2009
- "Historically, Intel has brought out its next generation of chips to thwart AMD and other competitors... " from *PC Mag* - Mar 28, 1995 - Page 91
- "Periphonics Corp. has brought out several software modules that allow its T-Comm 7 front-end processor to support retail point-of-sale (POS) terminal systems." from *Computerworld* - Sep 11, 1974 - Page 29
- "Raycom Systems, Inc. has brought out two new versions of its fiber-optic extenders for token-ring networks." from *Network World* - Jun 29, 1992 - Page 19
- "The General Dynamics that responsible for many simulation training systems has brought out the idea of Network-in-the-loop, ..." from *Computer And Network Technology - Proceedings Of The International Conference On Iccnt* 2009 [Pasge 73] ISBN 9789814466332.
- "Jam, in Collaboration with Whirlpool and Corian, has Received a fully interactive kitchen with soft lines and warm textures and Philips has brought out the Cafe Due ...* from *The International Design Yearbook* 2001 - [Page 179] by
  Michele De Lucchi, ‎Jennifer Hudson · 2001
- "I do not know how many new products he has brought out ..." from "Liability Insurance: Hearing Before the Subcommittee on Small Business"(1987)  United States. Congress. House. Committee on Small Business. Subcommittee on Antitrust, Impact of Deregulation, and Privatization·
- "... the product of that union — Nixdorf Computer Software Co. (NCSC) — has brought out its first software offerings to the IBM and compatible mainframe market" from *Computerworld* - Sep 8, 1980 - Page 47
- "The System Products Division also has brought out the PC XT/370, a PC combined with a machine that runs, ..." from *InfoWorld* - Oct 15, 1984 - Page 42
- "Computer Associates has brought out a feature-packed software package." from *InfoWorld* - Jan 30, 1984 - Page 9
- "Texas Instruments, the semiconductor company, has brought out a computer-aided design system which runs on an IBM Personal Computer..." from *New Scientist* - Nov 1, 1984 - Page 23
- "it has brought out eight new generations of computers in ten years" from *Performance Engineering at Work* - Page 404 by Peter J. Dean · (1999) quoting the *Wall Street Journal*, September 5, 1991
- "The manufacturer has brought out a line of three ruggedized IBM - PC / AT compatible computers." from *Control Engineering* - Volume 34, Issues 1-6 - Page 175(1987)
- "Hewlett-Packard Co. has brought out two new small computer systems interface (SCSI) subsystems for mass storage." from *Computerworld* - Aug 5, 1991 - Page 29
- "Since the initial launch of this product in August 2000, Oracle has brought out version 2.0..." from *Bridging the Global Digital Divide* [Page 52] by Jeffrey James · 2003
- "Two years later, Tandy has brought out the Model 100's successor, the Model 200, a laptop computer that offers ..." from *InfoWorld* - May 13, 1985 - Page 46
- "Apple has pulled the plug on the Mac Ilfx , until last year its most powerful machine, and has brought out a 33MHz Quadra" from  *Information Technology Digest* - Volume 1 - Page 20 (1992)
- "Unipress Software of Edison, New Jersey, has brought out its Uniplex II product, a Unix-based office automation package" from *InfoWorld* - Jul 8, 1985 - Page 21
- "Intel has brought out a steady stream of new microprocessors from the 8080 series to the Pentium in all its variations.variations " from *No-Nonsense Marketing: 101 Practical Ways to Win and Keep Customers* By Victor H. Prushan · 1997 ISBN 9780471157076, published by Wiley [page 120]
- "President Richard A. ... Boise has brought out new models at an aggressive pace , giving competitors little opportunity ..." from *Business Week* - Issues 3202-3211 - Page 79 (1991)
- "AccessData has brought out a product called NTpass, a NetWare password recovery program ..." from *Network World* - Nov 23, 1992 - Page 11
- "In addition to the 1900S series, ICL has brought out a new version of the old 1902A computer" from *New Scientist* - Apr 29, 1971 - Page 266
- "The Ingres Products Division of Ask Computer Systems has brought out what it calls the first terminal - based fourth - generation ..." from *Predicasts Technology Update* - Volume 47, Issues 1-26 - [Page 8] (1991)
- "  ... everyone has brought out a rival version—even HP, with its 65-font ProCollection cartridge." from *PC Mag* Jun 13, 1989 - Page 218
- "Now Xerox Imaging Systems (XIS) has brought out the first portable reading machine." from *PC Mag* - Mar 16, 1993 - Page 31
- "Microsense has brought out Sportster Si 14.4 Faxmodem , which has been developed by US Robotics." from *Dataquest: DQ. - Page 79 (1996)·
- ".. because a competitor has brought out a successful new product (i.e. one which sells) we will produce one as well." from *The Marketing Matrix: How the Corporation Gets Its Power* - Page 41 by Gerard Hastings · 2013
- "Lotus has brought out a product that will When used with the EGA ..." from *Personal Computing* - Volume 10 - Page 45 (1986) ·
- "Burroughs has brought out a series of competitors ' products ..." from *Time* - Volume 100 - Page 10 (1972)

I have skipped all results where "brought out" is used in the sense of "brought to notice" or in uses such as "brought out the best/worst in". I have also skipped the many uses in legal contexts where "brought out" refers to evidence developed during a case. I have also skipped many  uses in religious contexts, largely referring to the Exodus from Egypt. I think the above 24 published examples should be enough to refute the suggestion that such a use of "brought out" is "non-standard AmE English". Note that some are from technical publications specifically discussing product releases, and some are from books of instruction on the use of English.

Comment: Huh. Not disagreeing with ngrams necessarily but I would say the opposite, in my experience as a native AmE speaker: "coming out with" is better and more common than "bringing out." In the past tense I have an **extremely** strong preference for "has come out with" over "has brought out" to the point where I would—without hesitation—call "has brought out" non-standard AmE usage.

Comment: @randomhead I was thinking more in terms of news stories abpout future releases than past ones. But I think calling "has brought out" *non-standard english* is quite a bit over-the-top.

Comment: @randomhead  See my edits to the answer above, citing a dozen published examples including PC Mag and Computerworld. Would you still call "has brought out " non-standard AmE usage" I would also add that your contention does not match my experience as a native AmE speaker employed in IT for most of my life.

Comment: Note that 7/12 of your "brought out" examples are from Indian and/or Pakistani authors, and so are wholly irrelevant to my contention that it is non-standard **AmE** usage, let alone the fact that most of the examples are not talking about technology or consumer products. I will concede the *PC Mag* and *Computerworld* examples, though they are somewhat dated. My anecdotal experience is that "has come out with" is more widely used.

Comment: @randomhead It is hard to do a search finding examples specifically "talking about technology or consumer products." (although you did not limit your first comment on this issue to those uses).  I could have found more specifically US uses in those categories. But I think the ones above are sufficient to show that even if your memory is correct that "came out with" is more common when  announcing tech or consumer products, "brought out" is perfectly acceptable standard usage in **all** versions of English.

Comment: @randomhead I have aded an additional dozen examples, none from Indian sources, most from US-based publications, a couple from te UK-based New Scientist, and including quotes from the Wall Street Journal,, Infoworld, Control Engineering, Wiley  Books, Business Week, Network World, , Dataquest and Time; all dealing with computer or tech products. I have skipped many others from PC Mgg, Network World, and Computer World.

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, spring *brings out* blossoms and waitstaff *brings out* the baked Alaska, but business only ever *comes out* with new products and services.  I would have no idea to the intended meaning of, *Apple brought out a new phone.*  Sounds to me like the phone was buried in the back of the store.  Randomhead speaks truth.

Comment: @EllieK I am sure that describes your experience. But it does not match my experience, and it does not match the 24 printed examples cited above, nor the many more I found via Google Books. I suggest that your experience may not be fully representative on this point.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - It appears that the company Microsoft has never *brought out* anything they only *come out with.*  Could it be that your experience has been misguided by a careless interpretation of your NGrams?  Maybe its just a Microsoft thing? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Microsoft+has+brought+out%2CMicrosoft+has+come+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @EllieK Rermove the "has" from the "brought out" and the result is very different. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Microsoft++brought+out%2CMicrosoft+has+come+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 And even if Microsoft never chose to use "bring out", Apple, Xerox, and Lotus surely have. Anyway I think it established that fluent speakers, in a technology context, have used "bring out" and "brought out". That in my view is enough to establish tha as an acceptable natural usage, whether or not it is the most common.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - I did.  Now I ask you to change *has come out with* to *came out with* and you will see just how more often *came out with* is used to discuss new product offerings.  I would ask that you consider that your answer and tone may be incorrect. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Microsoft+brought+out%2CMicrosoft+came+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @EllieK That seems to show "came out" to be more common. But it does not show "brought out" to be unused or even rare.  Ngrams can be tricky, because a small change in the search can make a large difference. But as an existence proof, they can be useful. Both forms are used. Either is correct.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Here's one for Apple, as you mention and then make assumptions.  Please continue telling about *your experience* as a speaker of AmE.  You are way off base here. Are you thinking of the mid 1800s?   It may be your experience that *brought out* is used more often but your experience is yours.
 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Apple+brought+out%2CApple+came+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: I am not young, but my experience does not extend back to the 1800s. I didn't make assumptions about Apple. I noted that the use of 'brought out" in connection with their products is documented. I am not asserting which form ism more common, only that the "brought out" form is used enough to be "natural" Your latest Ngram shows it to be used, if less often than "came out".  I am not sure what statements of mine you think are incorrect or "off base", nor what changes you want me to make in my answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Here's one for Honda.  Looks like people once preferred *brought out*.  No longer, however.  Join us in the new millennium. 
 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Honda+brought+out%2CHonda+came+out+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @EllieK I am not asserting that one is more frequent overall than the other. I merely reported my experience and some google results. I think that searchs like this with a specific company name are probably too narrow to give a good idea of frequency. But my only point is that both forms are in active current use, which your searches seem to confirm. You seem to miss this. Comments like "Join us in the new millennium" are really not appropriate. I have made all the points I feel worth making on this thread.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Last comment from me.  In answer to your question as to how your answer should be changed.  You should say *coming out with* is more common than *bringing out*, as my three examples show.  Consider that my examples include actual company names and thereby ensure the comment refers to *coming out with new products* as opposed to *coming out of the kitchen with Baked Alaska.*